# Asymptotics for repulsive aggregation(-diffusion) equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, asymptotics

Consider the aggregation-diffusion equation
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \nabla (\rho \nabla(W\star \rho)) + \nu \Delta \rho,
$$
where $W:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is a twice continuously differentiable interaction potential, $\nu \ge 0$, and where $\star$ denotes convolution, that is, $(W\star \rho) (x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} W(x-y) \rho(y) \mathrm{d}y$. It seems that the case where $W$ is an attractive potential (that is $W(x)$ increases as $x\to \infty$) is well-studied, see for example the article I cite below. I suppose that makes sense as it is called *aggregation* equation.

However, I am interested in the case where $W$ is **repulsive**, on which I have found very little. In that case the solution should converge vaguely to zero, and I would be interested in asymptotic upper bounds on $\rho_t(0)$ in the case where $\rho$ is started from something nice and symmetric (say the standard normal density or something compactly supported), and where $W$ is a symmetric repulsive potential, like a standard normal density, a power law, anything really. I would even be interested in the case where $\nu = 0$, and specifically in $d = 2$.

---

*Carrillo, José A.; Craig, Katy; Yao, Yao*, [**Aggregation-diffusion equations: dynamics, asymptotics, and singular limits**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-20297-2_3), Bellomo, Nicola (ed.) et al., Active particles, Volume 2. Advances in theory, models, and applications. Cham: Birkhäuser. Model. Simul. Sci. Eng. Technol., 65-108 (2019). [ZBL1451.76117](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1451.76117)..

Comment: What exactly is $W\star \rho$ ? $\left(W\star \rho\right)(x)=\int \mathrm{d}^dx' \:W(x-x')\rho(x')$ ?

Comment: Yes exactly, I added this to the question. @DanielCastro

Answer (score 1):

(Too long to be a comment.) A hand-waving, physicist calculation of a specific example for $d=3$ goes as follows. It may be put in more rigours terms for higher but not for lower dimensions. Let's take

\begin{equation}
    W(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')=\frac{\alpha}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|},
\end{equation}

with $\alpha>0$ for a repulsive force. The one can show that $\nabla^2  W(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')=-4\pi\alpha\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')$. Since the potential is spherically symmetric let's assume that $\rho(\mathbf{x})=\rho(r)$ and just for notation omit the time dependence, then

\begin{align}
    \nabla\cdot\left(\rho(\mathbf{x})\nabla\left( W\star \rho\right)(\mathbf{x}) \right)&=\nabla\rho\cdot\nabla\left( W\star \rho\right)+\rho\nabla^2\left( W\star \rho\right)\\
    &=\nabla\rho\cdot\int d^3x'\:\rho(r') \nabla W(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')+\rho \int d^3x'\:\rho(r')\nabla^2 W(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')\\
    &=-\nabla\rho\cdot\int d^3x'\:\rho(r') \nabla' W(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')-4\pi\alpha\:\rho \int d^3x'\:\rho(r')\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')\\
    &=\alpha\int d^3x'\frac{\nabla\rho(r)\cdot\nabla'\rho(r')}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|}-4\pi \alpha\:\rho^2(r).
\end{align}

It's not hard to show that the remaining integral vanishes by explicit calculation. Then we have

\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial\rho(r;t)}{\partial t}=-4\pi\alpha\: \rho^2(r;t)+\frac{\nu}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial \rho(r;t)}{\partial r} \right).
\end{align}

Note that we cannot put $\nu=0$ (i.e. vanishing diffusion) because then we lose the solution. Since $4\pi\:\alpha>0$ you can see that the solution indeed dies away very rapidly, much more that typically linear Fokker–Planck solutions, but the non-linearity makes it hard to see analytically how this happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Going through it in detail I don't actually see why $\int dx' \nabla' \rho(x') / |x-x'| = 0$, could you elaborate on this? Clearly $\nabla \rho$ is antisymmetric and $1 / |x|$ is symmetric, but since they are integrated with a shift I don't see why everything must cancel.

Comment: @Peter . Since the gradient has only radial component it is proportional to $ \hat{\mathbf{r}}=\sin\theta'\cos\varphi'\hat{\mathbf{x}}+\sin\theta'\sin\varphi'\hat{\mathbf{y}}+\cos\theta'\hat{\mathbf{z}}$. The first two terms do not contribute because the $\varphi'$ integral vanishes, and you are left with $  \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta'\:\cos\theta'\sin\theta'\Big/\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta'}=0 $.

Comment: Ok, and the integral over $\theta'$ (which should be from $0$ to $\pi$, right?) is $\int_{-1}^1 (x / \sqrt{r^2 + r'^2 - 2rr'x}) dx$, which should not always give zero, or am I missing something? Say if  $r = r' = 1$, then it is $2 / 3$.